# how to compile gnuplot 5.0 with png -r pngcairo terminals

Tags: gnuplot

I have tried to compile gnuplot 5.0. Once finish compile I check for available terminals. There in the list I could not see terminal png or pngcairo. I also tried some options given in the release note for version 5 (http://www.gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html). Unfortunately, that could not help me.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and previously I used gnuplot ver 4.6.

Hope I could get some help.

Thanks

Comment: The cairo-based terminals are build in by default, provided you have installed all related development packages `lib...-dev`. I don't know which ones are required on Ubuntu

Comment: But gnuplot 4.6 works fine with png and pngcairo which are in the same machine.

Comment: Did you also compile 4.6 yourself?

Comment: When you do `./configure`, a lot of text is printed on the screen. The command checks if all required/optional libraries are available. You can aready there check if it finds the files for png support. One addition to Cristoph's comment: libraries contain executable code, but for compiling, you need headers, which tell the computer what's Inside the libraries. The headers come in extra packages called lib...-dev or similar.

Comment: Dear #sweber, I am using version 4.6 now. I shall try to compile some time near future.